# How to use a function in addEventListerner

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am learning the basics and trying to play around with JS. My question is how can I use a function written outside addEventListener. Right now I am using the following code:

```
ageCalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',function (event){
    var birthYear= prompt("What year you were born");
})
```

Now let's suppose I am trying to reuse a piece of code, how will I call the function from addEventListener. I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
ageCalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',ageInDays())


function ageInDays(){
    var birthYear= prompt("What year you were born");
}
```

Is it even possible or am I just hungup in solving an insolvable problem.

Comment: ageCalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',ageInDays)
not
ageCalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',ageInDays())

Comment: just provide the function name without the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can reuse functions  from outside.

try it like this:

```
ageCalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',ageInDays)


function ageInDays(){
    var birthYear= prompt("What year you were born");
}
```

Or even you can pass in the `prompt` function like this:

```
ageCalculatorButton.addEventListener('click',ageInDays(prompt))


function ageInDays(func){
    return function(){
        var birthYear=func("What year you were born");
    }
}
```